# Why not work KeyDown CTRL+KEY?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the following code, the two calls to `Zoom(0.1f);` and `Zoom(-0.1f);` work but I cannot trigger the two `UndoRedoManager.Undo();` and `UndoRedoManager.Redo();` calls for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void WorkspaceKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control == true)
        isCtrlPres = true;
    if (e.Shift == true)
        isShiftPres = true;
    if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
    {
        UndoRedoManager.Undo();
    }
    else if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.Y)
    {
        UndoRedoManager.Redo();
    }
    else if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus)
    {
        Zoom(0.1f);
    }
    else if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.OemMinus)
    {
        Zoom(-0.1f);
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking why `Ctrl+` and `Ctrl-` aren't recognized?

Comment: @Rup Very nice I wish I could upvote an edit.

Comment: Maybe, wrong keyboard layout?..

Comment: @Jim Mischel, no. I ask why CTRL+Y or CTRL+Z not work.  @vines, keyboard layout is correct.

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with the code you've got. If you try to break at either of the `UndoRedoManager` lines, does it break there? Quick test on my machine showed it breaking on all 4 key combos in that code.

Comment: @Joel Rondeau, but I'm also in the  Zoom(0.1f); and  Zoom(-0.1f); - worked. I see from debug.

Comment: @simply denis - I'm saying that breakpoints set for Ctrl+Y, Z, + and - all worked properly in my test, so I don't think that the problem is specifically with that part of it. If I had to guess, I think that there's an issue with your `UndoRedoManager` and not with this code.

Comment: @Joel Rondeau, if commenting `UndoRedoManager` still does not work. okay thanks will try for another check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Z)));
```